# I'm trying to new memory new heap memory in a function but it gives an error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, heap-memory

Here is my code, I don't know what's wrong with it, why can't I new heap memory?

```
int*& mergeSort(int* A, int N) {
    if (N == 1) {
        return new int(A[0]); //error
    }

    int mid = N / 2;

    int* A1 = mergeSort(A, mid);
    int* A2 = mergeSort(A + mid, N - mid);

    int* B = merge(A1, mid, A2, N - mid);

    delete []A1;
    delete []A2;

    return B;
}
```

Comment: Better use static arrays or vectors to implement your `mergesort`.

Comment: Why are you returning a reference to a pointer?

Comment: my guess would be because you try to return reference to pointer, and the nature of references is that you cannot reference temporary object, so I guess its the same problem with normal references

Comment: I'm return a reference to delete it below, when i use
if (n == 1) {
   int* B = new int(A[0]); // error new heap memory
   return B;
}

Answer (score 3):

This code fails because it tries to return an lvalue reference to an rvalue.  (The result of `new` is an rvalue).

The simplest fix is to just have the function return `int *` .

Without this fix, `return B;` also leads to undefined behaviour because you have returned a reference to a local variable.